# Searching an unordered set of objects by attribute and returning the corresponding object

Tags: c++, std, unordered-set

I need `FindIngredient` to return a `const Ingredient &` when searching by `Ingredient.name`. I need to used `unordered_set`. So I think I need  2 of them one to contain the objects and another one just to contain the string attributes `name` in order to search by string.

Is my approach ok or can I achieve it using only `unordered_set<Ingredient> ingredients`?

Following with my approach what how do I return in `FindIngredient` function? I want to return the object in  `ingredients` whose attribute name is the one found searching in `ingredientsByName`

```
      class Ingredient {
    public:
      string Name;
      int Price;
      string Description;
  };

class Pizzeria {
          unordered_set<string> ingredientsByName; 
          unordered_set<Ingredient> ingredients;
    public:
    
    void AddIngredient(const string &name, const string &description, const int &price)
        { 
            if(ingredientsByName.find(name) == ingredients.end())
            {
               throw "Ingredient already inserted";
            }
            else
            {
               Ingredient ingredient;
               ingredient.Name = name;
               ingredient.Price = price;
               ingredient.Description = description;
               ingredients.insert(ingredient); 
               ingredientsByName.insert(ingredient.Name);
               ingredients.insert(ingredient);       
            }             
        }
        
        const Ingredient &FindIngredient(const string &name) const 
        { 
            if(ingredientsByName.find(name) == ingredients.end())
            {
               throw "Ingredient not found";
            }
            else
            {
                return //  how Do I return  the corresponding Ingredient ???
            }
        
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind slower algorithm of search (`O(N)` time) then you can do a simple loop:

```
for (auto it = ingredients.begin(); it != ingredients.end(); ++it)
    if (it->Name == name)
        return *it; // Return found ingredient.
throw "Ingredient not found";
```

Loop above can be made even shorter:

```
for (auto const & e: ingredients)
    if (e.Name == name)
        return e; // Return found ingredient.
throw "Ingredient not found";
```

---

If you want fast algorithm of search (`O(Log N)` time) then instead of set you may use [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), i.e.:

```
unordered_map<string, Ingredient> ingredientsByName;
```

adding to map:

```
ingredientsByName[ingredient.Name] = ingredient;
```

then search in it:

```
auto it = ingredientsByName.find(name);
if (it == ingredientsByName.end())
    throw "Ingredient not found";
return it->second; // Returns found ingredient.
```

---

If you need sorted order of elements (by key) then you can use [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead of [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), map is always sorted by key (but 2-5 times slower in search and inserting for thousands of elements), while unordered_map is always unsorted (but 2-5 times faster in search and inserting).

---

If you want to store ingredients separately then you may use [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

```
unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<Ingredient>> ingredientsByName;
vector<shared_ptr<Ingredient>> ingredients;


// Adding element:

shared_ptr<Ingredient> ingredient = make_shared<Ingredient>();
ingredient->Name = "abc";
// Also fill other fields.

ingredients.push_back(ingredient);
ingredientsByName[ingredient->Name] = ingredient;


// Search:

auto it = ingredientsByName.find(name);
if (it == ingredientsByName.end())
    throw "Ingredient not found";
return *it->second; // Returns found ingredient.
```

Comment: In my lessons they did an example with an unordered_set<string>   and they said   unordered_set where the best for searching elements because they are indexed. In the assigment I am working on I have to do a similar thing but as you see  now they are objects rather than simple strings. I thought I could continue to use an unordered_set. Does using objects instead of strings change this?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Yes. In case of object you have to use `std::unordered_map` instead of set. Using objects changes things.

Comment: Is `ingredients` in the first example an `unordered_set` as I defined?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Very first example with simple loop can use set, everything as you defined in your code without change. The only drawback with loop is that it searches much slower than set's `.find()`.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO If you want fast search then you have to use map. If slow search is enough for you then you can use set and simple loop like in very first examples of me.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Actually set and map are very much related, they are almost same thing. Same algorithms and structures are used inside both of them. The only difference that map stores a pair of Key+Value while set stores only Key, that's the only difference, set is like a map with empty Value. So if you saw examples of set in your course, then you can be sure that using map is almost same.

Comment: I also need to print the ingredients name in alphabetical ordered later, so would it better to use a `map`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232446/discussion-between-arty-and-j-c-vegao).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to look using the `Name` member of `Ingredient`.

And you need to save the result in a variable that you can use when returning.

Perhaps something like this:

```
const Ingredient &FindIngredient(const string &name) const
{
    auto result = std::find_if(begin(ingredients), end(ingredients), [&name](Ingredient const& ingredient)
    {
        return ingredient.Name == name;
    });

    if (result == end(ingredients))
    {
        throw "Ingredient not found";
    }

    return *result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is this the only way to search an  object by attribute in an unordered map?. I am not supposed to use something as advanced as lambdas, which have not been introduced in my course.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Then a `std::unordered_map` is probably a better choice than a couple of sets.